# UnitOfWork as Repository object factory

Tags: c#, design-patterns

I have done some research about intentions of UnitOfWork pattern. In short, what I understood is that UoW is needed for transactions. But I saw some code examples where people use UoW as factory for Repository objects as well, one example is DbContext from EF. My first thought about it doesn't it break single responsibility principle?
In my current project I am using both UoW and Repository patterns. Here are my interfaces:

UnitOfWork:

```
public interface IUnitOfWork : IDisposable
{
    void Commit();
    void Rollback();
    IRepository<T> GetRepository<T>() where T : class;
}
```

Repository interface:

```
public interface IRepository<T> where T : class
{
    IQueryable<T> FindAll();
    IQueryable<T> Find(Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate);
    T FindById(Id id);
    void Add(T newEntity);
    void Remove(T entity);
}
```

My concern is `GetRepository<T>` method in `IUnitOfWork` interface. Should this method be here at all? Or should I move it somewhere else? What would you suggest?

**PS**
I am using NHibernate as my ORM tool, but I think this should not make any difference

Comment: Are you using [Linq-to-NHibernate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/624609/linq-to-nhibernate)?

Comment: I am still in architecturing state. But, yes, I am thinking about using Linq to Nhibernate

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### Leaky abstractions

A specific implementation should not *leak* into an abstraction. By making `IUnitOfWork` extend `IDisposable`, that's what you're doing:

> ```
> public interface IUnitOfWork : IDisposable
> ```

The goal of the abstraction, is to *abstract* implementation details away - in this case, the fact that you're using NHibernate. You had a *specific implementation* in mind when you created this interface, and that implementation *leaked* into the abstraction. What if you wanted to implement an `IUnitOfWork` that worked off a `List<T>`, for testing purposes?

Not *all* implementations of `IUnitOfWork` need to implement `IDisposable` - better leave that up to the implementation:

```
public class NHibernateUnitOfWork : IUnitOfWork, IDisposable
{
    private readonly ISession _session;

    /* implementation */

    public void Dispose()
    {
        _session.Dispose();
    }
}
```

```
public class TestUnitOfWork : IUnitOfWork
{
    /* implementation */
}
```

---

#### IQueryable

Every single implementation of the *Repository & Unit of Work* patterns I have seen, were different. Every single one.

Without seeing what your implementations and client code looks like (/how you're using these interfaces), it's very hard to tell whether you've done something wrong.

For one thing, exposing `IQueryable<T>` is *leaking* the query outside your repository, making it possible for client code to call `IRepository<T>.FindAll()` and then from there, add a `Where` clause or `Join` on another repository, which means the repository completely loses control of query materialization, which [unless I missed something] defeats its purpose.

By exposing a `IRepository<T> GetRepository<T>()` method on your `IUnitOfWork`, you're also making it possible for the *unit of work*'s clients to own the materialization of the query.

Whether that's good or bad, entirely depends on your architecture; I cannot tell just from the interfaces... I can only raise a flag.